# Как перенести числовые данные на новую сцену не наживая на кнопку в новой сцене?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Сами числовые данные я умею передавать, сохранил данные, перешел на новую сцену, нажал на копку,загрузил данные.А как делать так, чтобы данные(числовые) сами загружались при новой сцене(без нажатия кнопки загрузки)?

Answer (score 0):

OnLevelWasLoaded вызывается при загрузке новой сцены. Делаете там все, что нужно, вешаете его на камеру или специальный объект GameManager и все загружается каждый раз при загрузке новой сцены.